# Why is it that I’m still able to call a coroutine from another script, even though I marked it as private?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this private coroutine in my WinDialogue script:

```
private IEnumerator ActivateStars(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        _stars[i].SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
    }
}
```

And somehow I’m still able to call it from my UIManager script:

```
_winDialogue.GetComponent<WinDialogue>().StartCoroutine("ActivateStars", starCount);
```

How can that be if I marked it as private?

Comment: This is mere conjecture...But given that you are using the StartCoroutine that takes a string as an argument (instead of an IEnumerator, like the other overload), maybe it uses reflection (see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to get the IEnumerator, regardless of its accessibility (reflection lets you get private members and methods, most of the times passing an enum argument as BindingFlags.NonPublic. Note that using reflection is a little bit more expensive). If you are concerned by the accessibility, then use the other method override.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you start a coroutine by providing the method name as a string, then the Unity engine uses [reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to find the method at runtime, which doesn't care about the visibility of methods. This is not unusual for Unity. You might have noticed that methods like `Start` and `Update` are declared `private`, yet the Unity engine invokes them from outside the class.

If you would prefer proper software engineering principles - like names being resolved at compile-time and visibility rules being respected - use [the variant of StartCoroutine which takes an IEnumerator instead of a string](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) to denote the method.

```
WinDialogue dialogue = _winDialogue.GetComponent<WinDialogue>()
dialogue.StartCoroutine(dialogue.ActivateStars(starCount));
```

This will give you a compile-time error if `WinDialogue.ActivateStars` is private (or does not return an IEnumerator... or gets called with the wrong arguments... or is misspelled...).

Comment: Might be worth adding a comment that in C#, as long as Reflection is available, nothing is ever truly private. public/private/internal/etc are all just suggestions for other devs more than something that gets enforced.

Comment: @WilliamMariager: That's not entirely true.  It is enforced by the runtime for partially-trusted code: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/security-considerations-for-reflection

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The whole situation is absurdly complicated and I wish we had designed a simpler system in the original .NET code security model. The question of whether partial trust code gets private reflection is even more complicated than it seems; you can get into a situation where two assemblies that both lack ability to do private reflection on *other* assemblies can nevertheless reflect on *each other's private members*, which is surprising to say the least.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft In that case I wouldn't consider Reflection fully available, which is why I added that caveat. There are many ways to limit what can be done once you go into various security options in AppDomains.

Answer (score 13):

The answer from Philipp is correct; I'd like to extend it slightly by addressing directly your statement:

> somehow I’m still able to call it ... how can that be if I marked it as private?

The question indicates an important but subtle misunderstanding of what "private" applies to.  "Private" does NOT mean "cannot be called from outside".  Consider:

```
class C 
{
  private static void M() { whatever }
  public static Action A() { return M; }
}
```

Any code can call `M()` by invoking `C.A()()`.  Notice that in this scenario the call to M is made from code *outside* C; there is no *call* to `M()` inside `C`, merely returning a delegate to it.

And as Philipp's answer notes, there are other ways that code can access `C.M`, such as having been granted sufficient permissions to do private reflection.

What then does `private` mean, if not "this code can only be called from inside `C`?"

`private` means **the name of the thing declared may only be legally referred to by an *identifier* within the *accessibility domain* of a private member**.  That is, use of the identifier `M` to refer to the private member `C.M` is only legal inside the *accessibility domain* of `C.M`.

The private accessibility domain for a method of a class is *the region of program text* that falls within the outer `{ }` braces for the class (including partial class declarations and nested classes).

The thing that I'm emphasizing here is that `private` gives a restriction on **the source code of a legal program**. It says that the actual program text `M` may only be used to refer to member `C.M` if that program text appears somewhere inside the braces of the class declaration. An attempt to use the program text `M` outside of the accessibility domain will result in either binding to a *different* thing named `M`, or an error.

But the key thing to understand here is that `private` is all about *the legality of the text of the program's source code*. It is *not* a fact about behaviour at runtime! You can still call a private member; you just can't do it by writing *source code* that uses identifier `M` outside of the declaration of `C`.

Comment: Just to clarify, the compiled assemblies do have corresponding accessibility modifiers, both for compilers to obey when source code references the assembly and for the runtime to throw exceptions when a call is made "directly" (this might occur if assembly A referenced a type/member in assembly B at compile time, but the version of B resolved at runtime has changed to prohibit this access). But Eric's point is that you can't count on `private` to guard your members from all kinds of access (reflection, indirection, etc.); it's not a security feature.

Comment: @JoeSewell: That's exactly right; thanks for that clarification. Indeed, IL which makes a call to a private method will be flagged as *unverifiable*, and unverifiable code requires full trust to execute, so it is in that sense a security feature. But you should not treat accessibility modifiers as security features.